# Wordpress: Show only immediate parent in breadcrumbs

Tags: wordpress, breadcrumbs

I'm looking for a WordPress way to remove current and all grandparents from breadcrumbs. Basically, functionality is identical to history back button, but with page title. Don't want to do this in JS for obvious reasons. 
Any ideas?

Cheers!

Answer (score 0):

There is an easy solution to that, no need for breadcrumbs:

```
<?php if($post->post_parent) {
$parent_link = get_permalink($post->post_parent); ?>
<a href="<?php echo $parent_link; ?>">Back to <?php echo get_the_title(wp_get_post_parent_id( $post_ID )); ?></a>
<?php }
```